# Web Browser takes permission as owner

Tags: apache2

I am hosting a web server on my VPS, and users can access the sub directory and look at all the files.

[image]

I have tried to change the permission and it didn't help much, but when I change the owner permission and remove read, it stops the access.

[image]

That's what my permission for the folder looks like, It doesn't have any affect if I change group or public read access, only when I modify the owner, How can I fix this so a user can't just look at all files on my web server. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It's not clear what you exactly want to do. I assume `/public` is the web server directory, so by definition files in this directory are meant to be accessible via the web browser. If you want to make them inaccessible, there is no point in running the web server at all, because nothing will be accessible via the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to resolve this would be to use `.htaccess` rules. Here's a little template for you:

1. Create a file in your `/public` directory called `.htaccess`
2. Paste this into the file:

   ```
   Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
   Options -Indexes

   DirectoryIndex index.php

   <FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|inc|log|sql|user|token)$">
           Order Allow,Deny
           Deny from all
   </FilesMatch>
   ```

   Some of these rules can also be added to your `<directory>` entry in the domain configuration file (probably in `/etc/apache/sites-available`).

This `.htaccess` file will allow people to access files that are linked symbolically (within reason) and prevent directory indexes from being presented. It will also automatically direct someone to `index.php` if they just type your site's domain without a file name specified. If you do not have `index.php`, create an `index.html` with something in there and change the `DirectoryIndex` value accordingly.

In the `<FilesMatch>` section, files with certain extensions are specifically being blocked from external access. So if you had a file named `database-backup.sql` sitting in the `/public` directory (a bad idea, regardless), it would not be downloadable.

This is not a *complete* solution with regards to ensuring people do not scan your entire server, but it does reduce the ease that people might have doing so.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just creating an empty `index.html` file in the `/public` directory will usually also prevent displaying a directory index, if that's what OP wants.

Comment: So long as Apache knows to look, yes.

Comment: Hi, I just want my site to work normally without the user indexing my directories, and getting a list of all files if that makes sense.